# C Segmentation Fault from argc

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm currently trying to code my CS lab and am getting a Segmentation fault that I can not see. Am I doing something stupid or what? Code should take the command line args ("blah.exe hello world") and output them with a banner around them. Our class has no prior knowledge of C, but prior courses in data structures.

Example output

```
===============
= hello world =
===============
```

Source: compiled with gcc -std=c99 -Wall bannerize.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        if(argc <= 1) {
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        printf("TEST");
        int row_length = argc + 3; //3 for space after last word and 2 extra border chars
        for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++, row_length += strlen(argv[i]));

        printf("TEST2");
        char c;
        while((c=getchar())!=EOF) {
            printf("TEST3");
            for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++, printf("%c", c));
            printf("\n");

            printf("%c ", c);
            for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++, printf("%s ", argv[i]));
            printf("%c\n", c);

            for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++, printf("%c", c));
            printf("\n");
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Works fine for simply running with no parameters, but adding any command line arguments is giving a segmentation fault before it prints anything.

Comment: _giving a segmentation fault before it prints anything._ -- you do not know that to be true because your print statements are not flushing their output. Add `\n` at the end of each, such as `printf("TEST\n");` for better information. Alternatively, flush the output manually via `fflush(stdout);`.

Comment: You'll at least want to declare `c` an `int`. Besides `getchar` returning `int`, `EOF` doesn't (usually) fit in a `char` so your `while` won't end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++, printf("%s ", argv[i]))
> ```

This is a weird and twisted way to write a `for`. Consider what happens when `i == argc - 1`. You increment it and then you access `argv[argc]`. Which is necessarily NULL.

Instead of this cryptic (ZING!) way of writing the for, try using an actual body:

```
for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    printf("%s ", argv[i]);
}
```

The catch is that the body is executed only if the condition (`i > argc`) holds.

Comment: Notice the same error already in `for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++, row_length += strlen(argv[i]));` before any output is flushed.

Comment: I saw that loop on another post and always liked the one line. I didn't realize that i++ will get executed alongside the print statement, i thought the , just denoted that the body starts here, but I think it runs in conjunction to the i++, correct?

Comment: @CrypticStorm It is the "comma operator", you will seldom need it.

Comment: @Nabla Good catch, that's obviously the one that is causing the actual segmentation fault: it is unlikely it reaches the second identical problem.

Comment: All cleaned up, parentheses and brackets fixed. Thank you very much.